# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

[image error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zDxc.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glGUJ.png)

/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.0/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:1: Error: Can't have modifier 'final' here.
Try removing 'final'.

```
final class Utf16 extends Opaque {}
^^^^^
```

lib/transfers/downloads/download-manager.dart:20:42: Error: The argument type 'void Function(String, DownloadTaskStatus, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String, int, int)'.

- 'DownloadTaskStatus' is from 'package:flutter_downloader/src/models.dart' ('/C:/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.10.5/lib/src/models.dart').

```
  FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
                                     ^
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\tools\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\tools\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           68.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I want to build the APK but there is one error preventing it. Please help me fix the problem with this error.